# CODEIGNITER How to output 0 if select is NULL?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to ask, how to output 0 when its null ?
i have try IFNULL and COALESCE, it's not working.

```
$this->db->select('produk_tb.kode_produk, produk_tb.nama,  kategori_tb.nama as namakategori');
$this->db->from('produk_tb');

$this->db->join('penjualan_detail_tb', 'produk_tb.kode_produk = penjualan_detail_tb.kode_produk', 'inner');
$this->db->select_sum('penjualan_detail_tb.jumlah','jual');

$this->db->join('pembelian_detail_tb', 'produk_tb.kode_produk = pembelian_detail_tb.kode_produk', 'inner');
$this->db->select_sum('pembelian_detail_tb.jumlah','beli');

$this->db->join('kategori_tb', 'produk_tb.kode_kategori = kategori_tb.kode_kategori', 'inner');

$this->db->group_by('kode_produk');
$kontak = $this->db->get()->result();
$this->response($kontak, 200);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: try `echo is_null($var) ? '0' : $var;`  What's this `IFNULL`  Do you mean `IS NULL` your question is less then ... straightforward and causes more questions then it takes to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

Try as follows

```
$this->db->select('COALESCE(field_name, 0)',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

$this->db->select('select COALESCE(field_name, 0) as field_name_alias');
$this->db->from('your_table');

try this one